# How to know if data is ready

Tags: iphone, delegates, restkit

I am using RestKit Framework to parse JSON data coming from a web service. Once I send the request URL the data will be downloaded automatically and will be available in one of the delegate methods of RestKit . I am writing this as a re-usable wrapper class, so that I create an instance of this class wherever required and pass only the URL to download and rest of the process will be done by the class. Now, I have a problem, how the instance will know that the data is available to use after download ? How can i achieve that ? NSNotification or delegation ? Any coding examples or suggestions might help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are in right path. Is your question how to use NSNotificationCenter or Delegation in Objective-C ?

Comment: If you can't decide which of this patterns to use and you want a flexible code, I'd recommend to implement **both** and I'd also add the callback blocks as the third option.

Comment: @0x8badf00d Yes. You are right. I dunno how to implement delegation in objective - c. any examples might help ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the most convenient way to handle the callback in RestKit was to use the completion blocks. You can pass around this completion block to achieve what you are trying to do.

Here is an example of how you can create a completion block and pass it around.

```
-(void)startRequest {

    RKRequestDidLoadResponseBlock block = ^(RKResponse *response) {

        //your completion code
    };

    [self sendRequestWithCompletionBlock:block];
}

-(void)sendRequestWithCompletionBlock:(RKRequestDidLoadResponseBlock)completionBlock {

    RKRequest *request = [RKRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
    //configure request;
    request.onDidLoadResponse = completionBlock;

}
```